# Verify SCORM and LMS Connection

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm1.2

I am looking for a way to verify that that the SCORM object on the window in SCORM 1.2 still has a connection with the LMS and/or verify that values have been passed to the LMS, rather than just the SCORM object. We occasionally have users who are timed out of the LMS or have poor internet connection, but then are still able to complete the course without knowing that connection has been severed.

Is there any built in way to do this in SCORM 1.2, or any suggestions for a work around?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way in SCORM to do that since whether the LMS needs a connection
to a server and/or whether that connection needs to be active is entirely implementation specific. The SCORM runtime is intentionally self contained to the JavaScript object interface so it becomes a differentiating factor for the LMS how and how well it handles loss of connection. Additionally an LMS may intentionally provide the ability to play content in an offline state, for instance the Rustici Engine enables capability to play and record SCORM content while offline enabling an application to then capture the data back to the server once it detects that it has a connection.

Some LMS implementations may provide for errors to be set on SCORM calls if they detect a network connection loss and require one, but it is up to the content to use the interface and check for errors, and if no error is returned then the content is expected to assume that the state has been captured safely.